# Recursively appending to an array with ternary operator not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, conditional-operator

I'm trying to create a recursive function that returns an array of interger in a range of numbers.

If I use a ternary operator, the base case returns 'undefined'. I can't see where is the problem.

Using JSLint I get this message: "Wrap a ternary expression in parens, with a line break after the left paren."

The code:

```
function rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum) {
  return startNum === endNum
    ? startNum
    : rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum - 1).concat(endNum);
}
```

Comment: what happens if you try like this? ```(startNum === endNum) ? startNum
    : rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum - 1).concat(endNum);```

Comment: I think you need to return startNum as an array.  Otherwise it can't just concat a number.

Comment: @kvr I think that will make the JSLint warning go away. But that shouldn't be the reason the function is returning `undefined`. The ternary operator has a lower operator precedence than anything else in the expression, so it should be resolving in the way OP expects. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table

Comment: @kvr The JSLint warning keep showing and if I call the function with, i.e., rangeOfNumbers(5, 5) the function keeps returning "undefined"

Answer (score 2):

In your original example, you were just returning startNum which is a number.  Instead, we want to return an array containing the startNum so we can concatenate that value when returned.

Try this:

```
function rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum) {
  return startNum === endNum
    ? [startNum]
    : rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum - 1).concat(endNum);
}
```